# Problem on Möbius function on a finite poset

Tags: combinatorics

I try to solve excercise 3.129 in Stanleys Enumerative combinatorics vol 1. The problem is the following:
Let $P$ be a finite poset, and let $\mu$ be the Möbius function of $P \cup \{ \hat{0},\hat{1}\}$. Suppose $P$ has a fix point free automorphism of prime order $p$. Show that
$$\mu(\hat{0},\hat{1}) \equiv -1 \mod p.$$

My idea is this:
There is Philip Hall's theorem saying
$$\mu(\hat{0}, \hat{1}) = c_0-c_1+c_2-c_3+...$$
where $c_i$ is the number of chains $\hat{0}=t_0<t_1<...<t_i=\hat{1}$. 
Obviously $c_0=0$ and $c_1=1$. If we apply the fix point free automorphism on the chain we get another chain of the same length. If we apply it $p$ times we get $p$ chains, and then we are back at the chain we started with. Hence the number of chains of length $i$ has to be a multiple of $p$. But I guess I'm missing something here, because I have not used that $p$ is prime.

Comment: What is known about the effect of a map of posets on the M\^obius function? (That is, is there a relationship between $\mu(x,y)$ and $\mu(f(x),f(y))$?)

Comment: rogerl: Nothing really. But I think one should use Philip Hall's theorem. See the edited question.

Comment: I think you mean $\hat{0} = t_0$, not $< t_0$, and similarly for $t_i$.

Comment: You did use the fact that $p$ is prime. Otherwise you can't conclude that the number of chains is a multiple of $p$ --- it might be a divisor of $p$.

Comment: How can it be a a divisor of $p$? All the $p$ chains we get has to be different, because the automorphism is fix point free.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that if $p$ was not prime, then (say $p=4$), there could be only two disjoint $i$-chains, since applying the automorphism four times would still get you back to the original chain and still be fixed point free. But since $p$ is prime, the number of chains must be a multiple of $p$, as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of $i$-chains for $i\ge 2$; then $|X| = c_i$. If $\phi$ is the automorphism, then clearly the cyclic group of order $p$ generated by $\phi$ acts on $X$, and therefore by the orbit-stabilizer theorem any orbit is a factor of $p$; since $\phi$ is fixed-point free, we see that each orbit must have size $p$. So the number of $i$-chains is a multiple of $p$.

It follows that the value of the Möbius function is
$$c_0 - c_1 + c_2 - c_3 + \cdots \equiv c_0-c_1\mod{p} \equiv -1\mod{p}.$$

Note by the way that the $i$-chains need not all be disjoint; all that is required is that there are multiple orbits of length $p$ consisting of distinct chains.